# Error when making an array of picture boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The error I'm getting is "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"
This is at the line where I try to set the image as a bitmap. I've tried changing the location of the image multiple times and still doesn't help.

```
 Dim monkeys(4) As PictureBox
    For i = 0 To 4
        monkeys(i).Image = New Bitmap("H:\Monkey Casino\Monkey Casino\bin\Debug\monkey.bmp")

        monkeys(i).Width = 92
        monkeys(i).Height = 102
        monkeys(i).Top = 579
        monkeys(i).BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Next
    monkeys(1).Left = 48
    monkeys(2).Left = 237
    monkeys(3).Left = 425
    monkeys(4).Left = 609
    monkeys(5).Left = 793
```

Comment: `monkeys(5)` is an impostor (you did write `For i = 0 To 4`).

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use the `FlowLayoutPanel` and/or `TableLayoutPanel` controls.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually create any `PictureBoxes`.

If I give you an empty egg carton, does that mean that you can magically scramble some eggs? Of course not. If you never put any eggs in the carton then you can never get any eggs out.

That's exactly what you're doing. You create the egg carton (the array) but you never put any eggs (the `PictureBoxes`) into it so of course you can't get a `PictureBox` out of it to set a property. Think of an array as a group of variables. You have to initialise each element the same way you would a variable.